# How do I write a Capybara assertion that checks for the presence of a button and its enabled or disabled state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have an app that enables/disables buttons in response to things that happen in the UI.

I can easily use capybara to detect if a button exists

```
should have_button 'save'
```

but I have no idea how to verify the state of the save button.  That is:

*How do I write a Capybara assertion that checks for the presence of a button **and** its enabled or disabled state?*

I have hacked together a check for a disabled button; for enabled, I suppose that I could verify that there is a matching button and that there is no matching disabled button.  But this, to say the least, is clunky.

This seems like such a fundamental UI check, that I am sure that I have missed something, but I can't seem to figure out what.

---

Follow up based on gregates's answer:

As I mentioned in the comment, the Capybara behavior is dependent upon the underlying driver. We are using webkit, and it returns "true"/"false" string results. Apparently, other drivers return true/false.  The folks at Capybara are aware of the issue (github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/705), but they feel (probably correctly) that it isn't really their issue to resolve.

Rather than have my tests depend upon the driver I am using, I ended up creating a custom matcher:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_enabled do
  match do |actual|
    driver_result = actual[:disabled]
    # nil, false, or "false" will all satisfy this matcher
    (driver_result.nil? || driver_result == false || driver_result == "false").should be_true
  end
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :be_disabled do
  match do |actual|
    driver_result = actual[:disabled]
    (driver_result == "disabled" || driver_result == true || driver_result == "true").should be_true
  end
end
```

Then you can type:

```
user_license_area.find_button('Save').should be_disabled
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It appears that Capybara's handling of disabled elements has changed, so I figured I'd give an update.

To test whether a page has a button and is enabled, use:

```
expect(page).to have_button('Save')
```

To test whether a page has a button and is disabled, use:

```
expect(page).to have_button('Save', disabled: true)
```

This format works with `has_field?`, `find_field`, etc.

You can read more on this update at http://www.elabs.se/tag/capybara

**UPDATE**

The old link is broken. [This is the GitHub issue where the feature was discussed](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/982) and [this is the unfortunately barren documentation for the method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers#have_button-instance_method).

Comment: With the march of time comes the new features. I think this approach is the best way to solve this now.

Comment: link is now broken. (Also, I'm having some troubles with this solution these days, hence my interest)

Comment: @DaveMorse Huh, looks like elabs became part of Varvet. Anyhow, I added two new links to what I believe is up-to-date information.

Answer (score 14):

```
find_button('save')[:disabled].should eq "disabled"
```

Note that one line will effectively test for both existence and disabled state.

Edit: for enabled, try

```
find_button('save')[:disabled].should_not be
```

(Either of these tests may need to be tweaked depending on precisely how you disable/enable the button.)

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I still need to play around with this to get the test correct; but this is definitely the right approach to getting there.

Comment: Finally looped back around to this.  Here's a heads up, the Capybara behavior is dependent upon the underlying driver.  We are using webkit, and it returns "false" as a string.  Capybara is aware of the issue (https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/705), but they feel (probably correctly) that it isn't really their issue to resolve.

Comment: I needed to know when an ajax request had finished, and the only real change was that the submit button was no longer disabled. This worked perfectly for me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this. I think the best way is to just use css selectors

```
expect(page).to have_css("#save:enabled")
```

This example asumes that you have set the css id to save.

Answer (score 4):

There is be_disabled check

```
it "allows finding elements and checking if they are disabled" do
  expect(string.find('//form/input[@name="bleh"]')).to be_disabled
  expect(string.find('//form/input[@name="meh"]')).not_to be_disabled
end
```

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/2a51b817b355f6c1a5e95a471a87f1a492562e55/spec/basic_node_spec.rb#L108

Answer (score 2):

with minitest:

```
assert find('input[name=username]').disabled?
```

Answer (score 0):

From a similar situation where the user's actions in the UI (selecting document types) triggers buttons to become enabled...

With an id on the control, it becomes pretty clean to find the button (regardless of state) and assert a state of "disabled-ness".

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: Package generation not allowed unless a document type is selected
    Given I view the "Liberty and 4th Building Renovation" project
    When I view the Package Creator
    Then both document package generation buttons should be disabled

  @javascript
  Scenario: Package generation allowed when documents types are selected
    Given I view the "Liberty and 4th Building Renovation" project
    When I view the Package Creator
    And I select any document type
    Then both document package generation buttons should be enabled
```

And the supporting cucumber feature steps with Capybara:

```
Then(/^both document package generation buttons should be disabled$/) do
  expect(find_by_id('generate_pdf')).to be_disabled
  expect(find_by_id('generate_zip')).to be_disabled
end

Then(/^both document package generation buttons should be enabled/) do
  expect(find_by_id('generate_pdf')).not_to be_disabled
  expect(find_by_id('generate_zip')).not_to be_disabled
end
```